# jQuery append css link to iframe head

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web

I'm trying to append a css file to an iframe that is created on a page from a global script.  I can access part of it, but for some reason I can't append to the head.  It's not throwing errors either, which is frustrating.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                   
  $('#outline_text_ifr')
    .contents()
    .find('head')
    .append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/include/outline.css" media="all" />');
});
</script>
```

Comment: you open this page in the same domain?

Comment: It's under the same domain.  So cross-domain isn't an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append a stylesheet to an iframe with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624979/append-a-stylesheet-to-an-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: I have tried the append a stylesheet and it throws an error.  Perhaps I'm implementing it incorrectly.  But it says the frame doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is that the iframe is being created from an external script (one I don't have access to).  That would explain the error I get when trying to implement the method in the other post.

Comment: What ever solution you take, you'll need to wait for the load-event of the iframe instead of the ready-event of the parent document.

Comment: Dr. Molle, How would I go about doing that?

Comment: for example: `<iframe onload="doSomething()">`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var $head = $("#IFrame").contents().find("head"); 
var url = "Styles/styles.css";
$head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: url, type: "text/css" } ));
```

or

```
        $('#IFrame').contents().find('#div1').css({
            color: 'purple'
        });
```

Comment: Perfect!! Works for me once i used it :-)

Comment: How can we implement in typescript this?