# Add CSS to iFrame

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply CSS to iFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Right now I'm loading an iframe via jquery:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
  $('iframe').load(function() {
      $('iframe').show()
      $('#loading').hide();

    });
    $('#loading').show();
    $('iframe').attr( "src", "http://www.url.com/");

  });
```

And I have a custom style sheet that I would like to apply to that page. The page within the iframe is not on the same domain, which is why it's tricky. I've found solutions that allow you to add individual tags, but not entire stylesheets.

**EDIT:** The page in question is loaded via `file://` in Mobile Safari so the Cross-domain policy does not apply.

Comment: How the hell did you do that? It should be not allowed because of the cross domain policy of the browsers.

Comment: Could You add those solutions for individual tags?

Comment: @KARASZI on the contrary, that's exactly what `iframe`s are for.

Comment: @Jacek, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/217833#217833

Comment: I'm not understanding why you can't load a stylesheet from the iframe. I did this for a client once the same way you did. I had an ajax window load on the fly and i grabbed the data from serverside and I just embeded the stylesheet into the iframe dynamically.

Comment: @Peter: that's not cross-domain!

Comment: @pqsk, I can load the stylesheet that's already on the page, attaching **my** custom sheet is the issue.

Comment: @Peter, so you found your own answer?  That link provides all the details you would need.

Comment: @Karaszi the issue is that I'm loading it in mobile Safari via file:// in phonegap... there is no domain to begin with!

Comment: @Peter: then fix your question please

Comment: Do you use firebug or something of the sort to see what's going on when the iframe loads? that helps me a lot in debugging. Maybe if you could see what's going on put a screen shot, or tell us what you have tried/are trying.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Based on solution You've already found [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/217833#217833):

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "file://path/to/style.css"; 
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
frames['iframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

or more jqueryish (from [Append a stylesheet to an iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624979/append-a-stylesheet-to-an-iframe-with-jquery)):

```
var $head = $("iframe").contents().find("head");                
$head.append($("<link/>", 
    { rel: "stylesheet", href: "file://path/to/style.css", type: "text/css" }));
```

as for security issues: [Disabling same-origin policy in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556429/disabling-same-origin-policy-in-safari)

Comment: This ought to give security minded people headaches

Comment: Getting an error with the non-JQ way and no result with the JQ way. Error is `Cannot read property "document" of undefined.`

Comment: Then Cross-domain policy does apply after all

Comment: @Jacek ahh is that the CDP kicking in? Figured it'd give me a more specific error...

Comment: Try that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556429/disabling-same-origin-policy-in-safari

Comment: Any way to stop the flicker whilst the stylesheet is applied?

Comment: Does that work on IE8? I am trying to inject a CSS file but IE8 is not processing it. It works on IE11 using the compatibility mode, though.