# Inject multiple lines into iframe head of page same domain

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add CSS to iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960406/add-css-to-iframe)

I'm trying to put some styling and jquery into the head of a page 'within' an iframe.  This is on the domain so yes I can pass things into the head.  It works fine with just one <'line of code'>  but if I use  it won't execute.  I basically need the following to work:

```
$('#someFrame').contents().find('head').html('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/> <script src="link to jquery library"></script> <script src="link to my script">');
```

using .append instead of .html doesn't work (I've tried many times, it's 50/50 at best).  I can't just add multiple jQuery statements because each time I do it wipes the one before it out.

I tried one big .js file but it won't get past the 
not sure what I'm doing wrong. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah that like from @lolol worked...just need to change my format.  Thanks people!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960406/add-css-to-iframe

This is what worked from the link above.