# Override YouTube iframe styles

Tags: css, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to override YouTube iframe styles? For ex. I want to move YouTube logo up or down. It is an `img` with class `html5-watermark ytp-scalable-icon-shrink` but none of the styles in my css aren't working even using `!important` or setting the styles `onPlayerReady(event)`. Is there any way to override these external styles?

Comment: I think it is - I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960406/add-css-to-iframe?lq=1 but couldn't get it to work properly

Comment: Not sure you can because of **Same Origin Policy** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain

Comment: It's not working for me too. @MatRichardson