# Javascript making elements

Tags: javascript

I have made an 'IFRAME' element through javascript, but now I want to add the css to that iframe , I have made another src , which is included in the website body, so its working fine, but the style doesn't work, Now, I have to add the style sheet to that frame which I have in another file  but I don't know how to do it, can anyone please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add CSS to iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960406/add-css-to-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Set options  `X_FRAME_OPTIONS - ALLOWALL` on backend.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the style along with the iframe... no need for seperation.

```
iframeTag = document.createElement('iframe');
iframeTag.width = '1px';
iframeTag.height = '1px';
iframeTag.frameborder = '0';
iframeTag.style = '##INSERT STYLE';
```