# add <link> tag to iframe using angular2 js

Tags: angular

I've to show separate web application in my angular2 application. So i took `<iframe>`and gave it a url. Its loading webpage properly.
Now i want to control some css of web application present inside `<iframe>` from my angular2 application. Giving css directly in application will not work because `<iframe>`act as separate independent window. Is there a way to add css file to the web application shown inside `<iframe>`? I know we can do this with jquery but i need a way to do it through angular2.

Comment: Angular2 doesn't have special support for iframe. Can you post the code how you would do it in jQuery to see what you try to accomplish?

Comment: jquery code can be found in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624979/append-a-stylesheet-to-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: You can do it in plain JS or jQuery. Angular doesn't have any built-in support for this.